# copy all files with extension to documents directory

Tags: objective-c, ipad, nsdocumentdirectory

I am having a little bit trouble with copying files from an online place to the Documents Directory of the iPad in xcode.
The files that i want to download had to be the files with the extension 'xml'.

now i am doing this:

```
NSData *onlineLink = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/"]];
NSString *extension = @"xml";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:onlineLink error:NULL];  
NSEnumerator *e = [contents objectEnumerator];
NSString *filename;
while ((filename = [e nextObject])) {

    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename toPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL]];
    }
}
```

However this does not work, i get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteData fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000800'
```

Can anybody give me a hint why i am getting the error?

Comment: Which line is causing this error? Can you post the whole stack trace please?

Comment: Can you please post whole stack trace ?

Comment: i have solved the problem, the problem was that i did not correctly called the function...
thanks for your support anyway!

Comment: which function that you didn't call it correctly i need to use your code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

in the line:

```
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:onlineLink error:NULL];
```

contentsOfDirectoryAtPath should be an NSString, you are passing an NSData object

Comment: @Snowy Can you please post whole stack trace ?

Comment: @Snowy: please explain why you do not think that Jamie's post is correct. The error you posted is from trying to call `fileSeystemRepresentation`, which is an `NSString` method that gets called on the object that you pass to `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:`. You're passing an `NSData` object instead, `onlineLink`.